# How to loop through an API endpoint JSON Object in Vue & Axios?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios, rendering

I have an API endpoint which is a JSON object. I am using Axios and Vuejs to fetch the data into the DOM, but I am only able to get the whole object. When I tried to loop throught with the `v-for` directive it doesn't output the specific item in the object.

I fetched the data using Axios like so:

```
export default {
  name: 'Reviews',
  props: {
    title: String
  },
  data(){
    return {
      info: []
    }
  },
  // Life cycle hook that calls axios
  mounted(){
    axios.get('http://dev.muvtravel.com/index.php/explore/test?tripid=6590').then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
      this.info = response.data
    })
  }
}
```

Then tried loop through using `v-for`

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in info" :key="index">
   {{ item.establishment_address }}
   {{ item.phone }}
</div>
```

```
<template>
  <div class="reviews container-fluid">
    <h1 class="text-center">{{ title }}</h1>
    <b-container>
      <b-row>
        <b-col cols="12" sm="12" md="12" lg="4" xl="4">
          Column 1
        </b-col>

        <b-col cols="12" sm="12" md="12" lg="8" xl="8">
          Column 2
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>

    <div v-for="(item, index) in info" :key="index">
      {{ item.establishment_address }}
      {{ item.phone }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Reviews',
  props: {
    title: String
  },
  data(){
    return {
      info: []
    }
  },
  // Life cycle hook that calls axios
  mounted(){
    axios.get('http://dev.muvtravel.com/index.php/explore/test?tripid=6590').then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
      this.info = response.data
    })
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

Any help will be appreciate it

Comment: AFAICT this looks like this should work. do you get the array when you `console.log(response.data)`?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I am able to console.log the array and also it outputs the whole object if I add {{ item }} in the template. I want just the specific item infos though

Comment: Your code should work. Here s an example using static data and different layout https://jsfiddle.net/8jkxyhs6/  and it's working

Comment: @Daniel thanks, could you provide a working sample with the context of Axios?

Comment: jsfiddle won't allow due to CORS. but you can add a console log to compare with your result. Can you provide the example of your result from `{{ item }}`? I"m wondering if it get's parsed as text maybe `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Daniel it parsed in the DOM as the let response variable in your jsfiddle. What should I do?

Comment: can you try `{{ Object.keys(item).join(' | ') }}` instead of `{{ item }}` and see if the keys you're looking for are there (establishment_address, phone)?

Comment: @Daniel I get this: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14

Comment: @Daniel ok, I got it! I had to add response.data.data instead of response.data. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I checked to see if the API endpoint in your code was publicly open - it is.

From looking at your payload, the reason your code isn't working is because you're trying to iterate on an object. The `data` object that you're returning is the FULL payload from that API endpoint, which is an object `{"success": true, "data": [...]"}`.

To more clearly illustrate what I'm talking about, here's an example `fetch` you can run:

```
fetch(yourAPIEndpoint).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data));
```

When I run that, it prints this to the console:

```
{success: true, data: Array(15)}
```

When I edit the console.log above to output `data.data` like so:

```
fetch(yourAPIEndpoint).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data.data));
```

I get the array of locations that you are trying to set.

TL;DR: You need to set `this.info = response.data.data`.

Happy coding!